# Return Date Ranges based based on a given interval between two given dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a list of all DateRanges of a given interval between two dates.

For example if I have the dates 2015-04-01 and 2015-06-20 and when the interval is 20 the result should be

```
DateFrom       DateTo
------------------------
2015-04-01  2015-04-21
2015-04-22  2015-05-12
2015-05-13  2015-06-02
2015-06-03  2015-06-20
-------------------
```

Here is the query I am trying

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @Interval int = 20
SET @StartDateTime = '2015-04-01'
SET @EndDateTime = '2015-06-20';

WITH DateRange(DateStart,DateEnd) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime, DATEADD(d,@Interval,@StartDateTime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateEnd), DATEADD(d,@Interval,DateEnd)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateEnd <= @EndDateTime
)
SELECT CAST(DateStart as date) DateStart
    , CAST(DateEnd as Date) DateEnd
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
GO
```

Its returning the below result which is not exactly as my expected result above

```
DateStart   DateEnd
2015-04-01  2015-04-21
2015-04-22  2015-05-11
2015-05-12  2015-05-31
2015-06-01  2015-06-20
2015-06-21  2015-07-10
```

Here as you can see, there is an extra row outside the given dates and also interval between second row onward is 19 days, not 20. I understand its because I am adding a Day to the first field after **union all**

Please help me to fix this query or please suggest a better way to implement the same.

Comment: `2015-05-33` that is not a valid date

Comment: @Squirrel Really Really sorry for that.. :) Missed that.

Comment: Just change `<=` to `<` on this line `WHERE DateEnd <= @EndDateTime`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=adef3521d4c0300bfc2cca863b5f2f77

Comment: @Luuk But if the enddatetime is 2015-06-25 the last row would be 2015-06-21 2015-07-10 if we make just that change alone

Comment: Your question is not making this problem clear.  So, you should have a look at the current given answers, based on the CURRENT question, and determine if this is answered.  When you have an additional problem you should ask a new question, and make this additional problem clear.

Comment: You should be adding 19 days if you want 20 days.

Comment: If you want **dates**, then why do you use datetime datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to your recursive cte should be

use `CASE` to check for ending date. If it is greater than the required end date, set it to `@EndDateTime`

Also the `WHERE` condition should be

```
WHERE DateEnd < @EndDateTime


WITH DateRange(DateStart,DateEnd) AS 
( 

SELECT @StartDateTime,DATEADD(day, @Interval, @StartDateTime)

UNION ALL

SELECT dateadd(day, 1, DateEnd), 
       case when DATEADD(day, @Interval + 1, DateEnd) <= @EndDateTime
            then DATEADD(day, @Interval + 1, DateEnd)
            else @EndDateTime
            end
FROM  DateRange 
WHERE DateEnd < @EndDateTime

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It gives the correct output..

Answer (score 0):

If you want intervals starting every `@Interval`th day

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
declare @Interval int=20
SET @StartDateTime = '2015-04-01'
SET @EndDateTime = '2015-06-20';

WITH DateRange(DateStart,DateEnd) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime, DATEADD(d, @Interval - 1, @StartDateTime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(d, @Interval, DateStart),DATEADD(d, @Interval, DateEnd)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateEnd < @EndDateTime - 1
)
SELECT cast(DateStart as date) DateStart,cast(DateEnd as Date) DateEnd
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, But in this case, its not returning the last date 2015-06-20 . Also the gap is 19 days between dates